# Grant private access attribute

Tags: .net, assemblies, attributes

What's the name of the attribute that you apply on an assembly to allow access from another assembly to private methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't.

You can grant access to *internal* classes and methods to specified other assemblies via the  `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. However not all .NET language compilers respect this (IIRC C# does, but VB does not).

E.g. from System.Management.Automation.dll (since I have it open in Reflector):

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost,PublicKey=0024000004800000940000000602000000240000525341310004000001000100b5fc90e7027f67871e773a8fde8938c81dd402ba65b9201d60593e96c492651e889cc13f1415ebb53fac1131ae0bd333c5ee6021672d9718ea31a8aebd0da0072f25d87dba6fc90ffd598ed4da35e44c398c454307e8e33b8426143daec9f596836f97c8f74750e5975c64e2189f45def46b2a2b1247adc3652bf5c308055da9")]
```